# Why BASH_SUBSHELL is always 0 no matter `lastpipe` is enabled or not?

Tags: bash, subshell

I have done some research on `pipe` and `subshell`

> Each command in a multi-command pipeline, where pipes are created, is executed in its own subshell, which is a separate process (see Command Execution Environment). If the lastpipe option is enabled using the shopt builtin (see The Shopt Builtin), the last element of a pipeline may be run by the shell process when job control is not active.

test code

```bash
#!/bin/bash


set +m

shopt -u lastpipe
shopt | grep lastpipe

function test() {
  echo "This is first pipe"  | echo $BASH_SUBSHELL
}

test

shopt -s lastpipe
shopt | grep lastpipe

function test() {
  echo "This is first pipe"  | echo $BASH_SUBSHELL
}

test
```

Output is

```
lastpipe        off
0
lastpipe        on
0
```

Expected result is

```
lastpipe        off
1
lastpipe        on
0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that variable substitution is performed *before* the pipeline runs. When you write:

```
echo "This is first pipe"  | echo $BASH_SUBSHELL
```

The `$BASH_SUBSHELL` is expanded **in the current shell** before it runs the pipeline. To properly perform your test, you would need to place your `echo` statement in a function to defer substitution:

```
test_subshell() {
  echo $BASH_SUBSHELL
}
```

Then you will see different behavior:

```
$ test_subshell
0
$ echo "This is first pipe" | test_subshell
1
```

Comment: I disagree. BASH_SUBSHELL is expanded in the child shell.

Comment: I am happy to entertain the idea that my answer is incorrect, but rather than just telling us it's wrong can you provide an updated answer? Why does `echo foo | echo $BASH_SUBSHELL` show a different value than `echo foo | test_subshell`?

Comment: yes, so I can't answer, so I guess until I can prove otherwise, you can ignore me. Does `export BASH_SUBSHELL; echo | env | grep BASH_SUBSHELL` prove it? Or `echo | { echo $BASH_SUBSHELL; }`? I tried reading docs, and I do not think it is 100% clear _when_ after tokenization the expansions happen.

Comment: I always thought that variable substitution of the entire pipeline happens before the pipeline is executed...e.g., the bash man page says, "Expansion is performed on the command line after it has been split into words.", and I took that to mean, "before executing anything".

Comment: For example `echo $BASHPID; echo | echo $BASHPID` returns two different pids.

Comment: I confess, I am puzzled!